# leaflet fitBounds with multiple marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jquery

I have created two checkboxes. If I check one it will zoom to a point with marker. If I uncheck the checkbox the marker removed. Similarly second one is working. But I want to do if the two checkboxes are checked at a time it will zoom at a position where both are visible. Again when one of it checkbox is unchecked it will zoom to the points best fit position. I know that fitbounds can solve this but couldn't imliment it. Here is my code I used. Any suggestion will be a great help. Thanks

```
<input type="checkbox" name="One" id="one" >One</input></br>
<hr><input type="checkbox" name="Two" id="two">Two</input></br>

 $('#one').click(function(){
     if($("#one").prop('checked') === true) {
         var marker = L.marker([32.304255,-64.752098]).addTo(map).bindPopup('One');
         map.setView(new L.LatLng(32.304255,-64.752098), 16);
         marker.on('dblclick', function(){
         marker.openPopup();
         });
     }
 });
 $('#two').click(function(){
     if (this.checked) {
         var marker= L.marker([32.319343,-64.728066]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Two');
         map.setView(new L.LatLng(32.319343,-64.728066), 16);
         marker.on('dblclick', function(){
         marker.openPopup();
         });
      }
 });

var xLayer =[];
function clearLayer(){
for(var i =0; i < xLayer.length; i++)
    map.removeLayer(xLayer[i]);
    xLayer = [];
};

$('#one').click(function(){
    if($("#one").prop('checked') === false) {
    clearLayer();
    }
});
$('#two').click(function(){
    if($("#two").prop('checked') === false) {
    clearLayer();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:
have a look at [L.LatLngBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds)

**Long answer**:
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/deciob/vVdyM/26/) is a working example on jsFiddle (with comments) that does what you are trying to accomplish. (It also uses underscore.js)

**In general**:
when writing client-side JavaScript code, it is very easy to get very quickly into a mess. Try to avoid repeating code and try re-factoring common functionality into short functions. Every function, ideally, should encapsulate an atomic bit of functionality (it should not accomplish too many things).

Comment: Thanks. One little help. When I am trying to incorporate the code its returning an error like "_ is not defined" and indicating "var markerObj = _.find( markersObj, function (obj)" this line. What I have to do to work the code perfectly?

Comment: Because you need to incorporate [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) in your code. Something like this should work: '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>'

Comment: To be more clear: you need to include underscore.js the same way you are including leaflet.js.